# I am getting [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.zyte.com/blog/>

Tags: get, web-crawler, processing

I was only trying the example code given in the start page of scrapy to learn it, but faces the error with every web page I tried.  Not sure how to resolve it.

```
2023-11-04 07:14:14 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.zyte.com/blog/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 892, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 79, in _parse
    return self.parse(response, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 82, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError(
NotImplementedError: BlogSpider.parse callback is not defined
```

Comment: When using Scrapy, you need to define the parse method in your spider to handle the responses and extract data from the web pages. More information you can find here: [parse(response)](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.Spider.parse)